# Qt Designer 4.8 Crashes on startup on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

Has anyone else been able to run Qt Designer from the Qt library installer provided on http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/downloads#qt-lib ?

Qt Designer (which gets installed in /Developer/Applications/Qt) crashes on startup when I try to open it, but qtdemo and other applications work fine.

Comment: I'm going to try installing Qt from source instead via homebrew, to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried installing Qt via homebrew instead, and Qt Designer works there but PySide (which I also want to use) doesn't.

Comment: `brew install pyside` I guess that taught me a lesson, don't use Installer packages when Homebrew packages are available. They often work better, are newer, and more contained.

Answer (score 1):

On inspection of the stack trace it seems that it doesn't like it if dbus is not installed.
You can grab dbus from http://dbus.freedesktop.org/releases/dbus/.

To install it you just need to:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You obviously need Xcode+gcc installed.